# Can I used polynomial congruence for prove 3 divide $n^3-n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, congruences, polynomial-congruences

I'm not sure this method can work to prove  3|$n^3-n$?

by let we have polynomial congruence

$n^3-n\equiv 0(mod3)$

then if all residue class mod 3 are the roots of congruence 3|$n^3-n$

the residue for mod 3 are 0,1,2

then I plug each of them in congruence

start by 0

$0-0\equiv 0(mod3)$ congruence

then 1

$1-1\equiv 0(mod3)$ congruence

and 2

$8-2\equiv 0(mod3)$ congruence

then concluded 3|$n^3-n$

Does it work ?

Comment: Are you supposed to prove this for all natural numbers? If so, have you considered all possible cases?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0  yes I try to prove on natural numbers,but I'm not sure it will cover all possible cases

Comment: How about using induction ?

Comment: @SMath I don't like induction so  much -*-  that why I try to prove another way

Comment: This looks like a perfectly good proof to me

Comment: The equivalence classes partition the natural numbers, so I would consider the proof to be complete (if a little rough). How well this is received by your instructor would depend on the tools they have allowed you to use.

Comment: @ASKASK to me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can justify that the problem is reduced to remainders modulo $3$ like this:

Let $n=3q+r$ with $r\in\{0,1,2\}$ then

$n^3-n=(3q+r)^3-(3q+r)=27q^3+27q^2r+9qr^2+r^3-3q-r\equiv r^3-r\pmod 3$

Then your method of evaluating the value for each $r$ is fine, and you get the conclusion it works for all integers.

Answer (score 3):

$n^3-n$ factors as $(n-1)n(n+1)$. For any integer $n$ it is easy to prove that one of the factors must be divisible by $3,$ so $n^3-n\equiv0\pmod3.$

Comment: ah,I forgot the simple fact  thank  ^ ^

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works. (You should state that it is $n$ you are taking the equivalence classes of-- you never actually stated that).  If $n \equiv 0, 1 ,2 \mod 3$ then $n^3 -n \equiv 0-0, 1-1, 8-2 \mod 3$ respectively.

You can make it a tad more wieldy you could say $n\equiv -1, 0, 1\mod 3$ to get $-1+1, 0-0, 1-1 \mod 3$ respectively.

And that is fine.  It does do everything a proof needs to do: it demonstrates irrefutably that the statement is true.

......

But 1) the text probably want a more intuitive, less brute force method and 2) for a more complex situation of a possibly high modulus such a proof may not be feasible or practical.

What they are getting at is to factor $n^3-n = n(n-1)(n+1)$.  Those, $n, n+1, n-1$ are three consecutive integers so one of them must be divisible by $3$.

.......

Consider instead $n^7-14n^5 + 49n^3-36n$ and proving it is divisible by $5040$ is going to be impractical be brute force ($5040$ cases to check!)  (Although a computer doing it would be an acceptable, albeit inelegant proof).

But factoring it as $(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ and noting it is a product seven consective integers so one of the terms is divisible by $7$, and least  one is by $5$.  Two are by $3$ and three are by $2$ with at least one by $4$.  So $7*5*3^2*2*2*4=5040$ divides it.